# Google sign-in via Chrome popup: how can I integrate it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-oauth

Some days ago I opened the [Flipboard](https://flipboard.com/) website and a Chrome popup (similar to the "*Do you want to communicate your position?*" or "*Do you want to receive push notifications?*" popups), show up asking me if I want to use one of Google accounts stored in Chrome to log in into Flipboard.

I chosen one of them, and I was immediately authenticated (without page refresh).

Actually, this behaviour is not present on Flipboard, maybe Flipboard's developers are testing it but... how can I try it?

I searched on the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), but I found nothing.

Do you know anything?

Thanks